# How to implement Digital Signatures in node.js

Tags: node.js, digital-signature, dsa

I'm new in node.js and I need to implement digital signatures.The Scenario is that, a user "A" will send some data by signing it with its private key (Stored on local machine) on to the server. So any other user "B" can verify it by decrypting the data with public key (Stored in DB on server) of "A". 
Now following are my questions.
How to generate public private keys?
How to store private key on local machine?
How to sign data using private key and how to verify it using public key?

Comment: Here's a tutorial on what digital signatures are: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography/cryptography_digital_signatures.htm.  Here's an example of generating one, in Java: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/SimpleDigitalSignatureExample.htm.  I would dive into that and come back with specific questions, when you have them.

Answer (score -1):

I found the below flow diagram on google. You can use this to get a grasp of he functionality. You can use [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jws) to implement your signatures. Not sure if this solves your problem or not, but I hope it will help you in getting some clarity.

[image: diagram]

Comment: consider adding some extended information on why and how that image helps. As a side note, posting just links doesn't get you far in SO.